# Installing a smart switch timer - 8 wires in gang box?

Tags: wiring, smart-switch

I am replacing a single pole light switch with a smart switch with a timer.  I have successfully installed 8 others but have not seen this many wires in a gang box before.  Could someone explain how to combine these wires to operate the smart switch?  I would appreciate any ideas you may have.
[image: Red,Black,White on left - Ground wires pointing up - Black,White on right - Black, White facing down]

Comment: How were the wires connected before you removed the old switch?

Comment: What did the old switch control?

Comment: Did you take  picture before you disassembled everything?

Comment: The switch controls a ceiling light.  The neutral wires were all attached together with the red and black wire on the left and the black wire from the bottom.  This was connected to the switch.  A pigtail ran from this to the black wire on the right, which was also connected to switch

Comment: I did not take pictures prior to changing the switch.  I am kicking myself now but I (in my stupidity) thought this was pretty straight forward and connected the smart switch the same way it was connected to the single pole switch. When I did this I was able to  turn the light on but not able to turn it off.  I thought this was a matter of connecting the neutral wires differently, which resulted in this :(

Comment: Do you have a meter? Can you tell us which wires are hot?

Comment: The only hot wire is the red one on the left

Comment: Every time I see something like this, I think "Why didn't you take a _before_ picture???" Then I think, because, just like me, this person thought it would be easy, and ended up being just as lost as I have been in the past...

Answer (score 3):

Here's the thing.  Wires are NOT color coded for novices.  Actually the color codes mean:

- Red, white, black = this cable has 3 wires + safety ground.
- Black, white - this cable has 2 wires + safety ground.

There's a rule that white must be used first for neutral and then always-hot, but that's the end of the color coding in North America.  So how do we tell how these go?

### That information is recorded by *how they are connected*.

And when we get a photo like this, with all the wires splayed out for the camera, that was a misguided choice that leaves us nothing to say but "call an electrician".  There are simply too many possibilities to walk someone through "guessing".

Fortunately for you, you remember some things that *make sense* and cross a bunch of possibilities (most) off the list.

"The neutral wires were all attached together" (from a comment). *Whew*. Lucky us.   They should all be reconnected together (properly) and pushed into the back of the box.  If you are anticipating needing neutral for a smartswitch, add a pigtail to that bunch of now 4 (this is a job for a red wire nut) and cap off the pigtail for now.

Now that's off the table.

The good news is that all remaining wires are hots.  Normally, experimenting is *super dangerous*, but in this case, they all either connect to each other or to the opposite side of a switch.  Switches connect the 2 terminals, so that means if we connected them *all* together, your house wouldn't burn down; just a light would be stuck on.

So we need to identify 2 wires in particular out of these 4 hots.  One is supply from the service panel - this is hot at all times.  The other is the switched-hot going up to the lamp.  We can guess that the other wires carry "always-hot" onward to other points of use.  Notably, these points-of-use are now dead.

There's a "convention" that the red wire is used "preferentially" for a switched-hot, but that's only a common practice, not a standard nor requirement.

Normally, we crank down super hard on wire nuts - so hard that if the wires went in twisted another way, this un-twists them and twists them the new way.  But for experimentation, just feather-touch them - just enough to hold them together.

Naturally, *and I know you already know this*, you do all work with the power off, and only turn the power on to test the result of a new configuration. Cap off any wires you are not testing with, even white wires that may be exposed - they can be hot (that's why they have insulation lol).

So anyway I would connect A to B (capping off C and D).  If something that had lost power comes back on again, then either A or B is the always-hot.  Now try A and C.  You quickly find the always-hot.   Once you have that, then keep trying the always-hot with A, C or D until the lamp comes on.  Now you have switched-hot.

I like to mark switched-hot with red tape and always-hot with black tape (if they aren't already).  This also happens to be the color convention used by *most* smart switches.

Then it becomes very straightforward: Join all blacks.  Join all reds. Join all whites. Done!

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I will try my best to not burn my house down!  :)